# Perl script to find out add/edit or delete done by an user for a workspace in Perforce

Tags: perl, perforce

perforce list out the files submitted by an user i.e.
p4 changes -u 
what i would like to do is write a small function in perl which will find 
what changes have been submitted by user 
what operations has been performed for those changes i.e. add, edit or delete and print those .
so logic is something like this 
1. find changes submitted by an user
2. what operation has been performed on those changes 
result :
user has 5 change list submitted after date ...
5 add, 2 delete and 1 edit operation found in all changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are stumbling on.

- If it's connecting to perforce from Perl, you can use one of several CPAN modules for the purpose: see the first hits in googling for ["CPAN perforce"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=cpan+perforce).
- If you wish to parse STDOUT output from `p4 changes -u` command line instead, please post the exact output format from the command, what you tried so far to parse it, and desired matching output from your program.